# psych::corr.p(): How can I round p-values to three decimals?

Tags: r, p-value, psych

I want to know the p-values of my correlation matrix rounded to three decimals **and** adjusted using Benjamini Hochberg correction.

To this goal, I tried using

```
psych::corr.p(as.matrix(cormatrix), n = 999, adjust = "BH")
```

However, in this function p-values are rounded to two decimals and

```
round(sych::corr.p(as.matrix(cormatrix), n = 99, adjust = "BH"), 3)
```

gives me the error

> non numeric argument for mathematic function

I guess I could use `p.adjust(pvector, method = "BH"), 3)`. But `corr.test` only gives me p-values that are adjusted in some form, so another adjustment will likely result in overestimated p-values.

I cannot simply use `round(corr.test(), 3)` which would give me adjusted p-values and three decimals because in my correlation matrix are bivariate correlations as well as partial correlations for which I want to adjust p simultaneously.

Comment: Return the result corr.p to an object and inspect it. `cp <- psych::corr.p(as.matrix(cormatrix), n = 999, adjust = "BH") ; str(cp)` . You should see a list of objects - select the one that you want to `round`. Also note the help page `?psych::corr.p` provides details on all of the retuned values

Comment: thanks @user20650! that little tip helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`round(corr.p(cormatrix, n = 999)$p, 3)` works